# How to remove elements in an array in order to another array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to write a function in C, that removes the second array's elements from the first array if the first array fully contains the second array in the exact same order.

I know it's complicated to ask in words, so here are some examples:

If Array-1 is `hello` and Array-2 is `lo`, then the output should be `hel`.

If Array-1 is `hello hello` and Array-2 is `lo`, then the output should be `hel hel`.

If Array-1 is `hello` and Array-2 is `call` *(the first array does not contain all of the second array)*, then the output should be `hello`. *(It shouldn't be changed.)*

I wrote some code but when I try 2nd example (the `hello hello` one), it gives me `hello hel`, not `hel hel`.

```
char removeText (char a[], char b[], int lengthA, int lengthB) {

  int indexB = 0, i=0;
  char d[lengthA];

  for (; i<lengthA; i++) {

    if (a[i]==b[indexB]) {
      indexB++;
      if (indexB==lengthB) {
        for (int k=0, j=0; k<i-lengthB; j++, k++) {
          d[k] = a[j];
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      i -= indexB;
      indexB = 0;
    }
  }

  printf("%s", d);

  if(indexB!=lengthB) {
    return *a;
  }

  return *d;
}

int main(void) {

  char a[] = "hello hello";
  char b[] = "lo";
  int c = 11;
  int d = 2;
  
  removeText(a, b, c, d);

  return 0;
}
```

The output should be given with `return`. The `printf("%s", d);` part is just for trying if the code works or not.

I know what's wrong in my code. The

```
if (indexB==lengthB) {
    for (int k=0, j=0; k<i-lengthB; j++, k++) {
        d[k] = a[j];
    }
}
```

part causes the error but how can I fix it?

Comment: The return type char of the function does not make a sense.

Comment: If the first array is "banana" and the second is "ana"; would the result be "b" or "bna"?

Comment: `strstr` could help here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the lines:

```
for (int k=0, j=0; k<i-lengthB; j++, k++) {
    d[k] = a[j];
}
```

Each time you find a pattern in `a`, you copy all `a` data into `d`, cancelling what have been done before.

To highlight this, you should modify your code with some debug info:

```
printf("copy to d from a, indexd for %d to %d\n", 0, i-lengthB)
for (int k=0, j=0; k<i-lengthB; j++, k++) {
    d[k] = a[j];
}
```

You could have noticed too that `k` and `j` are always equal.

One more question, how do you code if the pattern to remove is not at the end of input, or is not present in input ? Try it.

---

To solve your problem, I would advice a different approach: have a counter for ignored character in `a` and copy the character when pattern is not found, something like:

```
char * removeText (char a[], char b[], int lengthA, int lengthB) {

  int indexB = 0, i=0;
  int ignored = 0;
  char d[lengthA] = "";

  for (; i+ignored<lengthA; i++) {

    if (a[i+ignored]==b[indexB]) {
      indexB++;
      if (indexB==lengthB) {
        ignored += lengthB;
        printf("ignored = %d\n", ignored);
      }
    }
    else {
      i -= indexB;
      indexB = 0;
      printf("d[%d] = a[%d] (%c)\n", i, i+ignored , a[i+ignored ]);
      d[i] = a[i+ignored];
    }
  }
  printf("%s", d);
  strcpy(a, d);
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked but there is one little problem. When I try just ```hello``` and ```lo```, the output is ```hal�```, but it should be just ```hal```. What causes that strange character? The ```lengthA``` is 5 and ```lengthB``` is 2, as needed.

Comment: I think it's because the `\0` is missing from `d`.
One solution to fight this problem is to initialize `d` to `""` (post edited)